# put two divs next to each other

Tags: html, css

I am trying position two divs next to each other.
html

```
<div id="status">
  <div id ="wrapLeft">
    <input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
    <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
  </div>
  <div id ="wrapRight">
    <input type="text" placeholder="url"/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="url"/>
  </div>
  <div id="clear"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
  body {
    font-family: "Segoe UI", "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
  }      #status {
    /* avoid an excessively wide status text */
    white-space: pre;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 600px
  }
  input{
    width:100px;
    height:25px;
    border-top:0px;
    border-left: 0px;
    border-right: 0px;
    outline: none;
  }
  #wrapLeft{
    position: relative;
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
    float: left
  }
  #wrapRight{
    position: relative;
    width: 65%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    float: right;
  }
  #clear{
    clear:both;
  }
```

Yet somehow the divs arent on same level, the right one is below the left one. How to fix this? I tried using left and right float but it doesnt align which should. What could cause this?[example](https://jsfiddle.net/h7pLx8kr/1/)

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Use `display:flex` for main `div`.

Also look at the CSS, I have removed some of CSS.

```css
body {
    font-family: "Segoe UI", "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
  }      #status {
    /* avoid an excessively wide status text */
    white-space: pre;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  #status{
  width:100%;
  display:flex;  /* It's Important */ 
  }
  input{
    width:100px;
    height:25px;
    border-top:0px;
    border-left: 0px;
    border-right: 0px;
    outline: none;
  }
  #wrapLeft{
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;

  }
  #wrapRight{
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
  }
```

```html
<div id="status">
  <div id ="wrapLeft">
    <input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
    <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
  </div>
  <div id ="wrapRight">
    <input type="text" placeholder="url"/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="url"/>
  </div>
  <div id="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I agree, use flex box. I tried using grid but only the latest browsers support this. https://codepen.io/JohnnyBizzel/pen/rzdGwM

Comment: Ok now I have added a new way :).

Answer (score 1):

For older browser support, you can use CSS `float` and `width` properties.

```css
body {
    font-family: "Segoe UI", "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
  }      #status {
    /* avoid an excessively wide status text */
    white-space: pre;

  }
  

  input{
    width:100px;
    height:25px;
    border-top:0px;
    border-left: 0px;
    border-right: 0px;
    outline: none;
  }
  #wrapLeft{
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    background: black;
height: 100%;
  }
  #wrapRight{
    float: right;
  width: 70%;
    background: red;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top:-23px;  /* Important*/
  }
```

```html
<div id="status">
  <div id ="wrapLeft">
    <input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
    <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
  </div>
  <div id ="wrapRight">
    <input type="text" placeholder="url"/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="url"/>
  </div>
  <div id="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've looked into it and the issue is caused by white-space : pre in the css. So you need to remove that and then position the inputs accordingly inside the divs.

```
<style>

  body {
    font-family: "Segoe UI", "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
  }      #status {

    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 600px
  }
  input{
    width:100px;
    height:25px;
    border-top:0px;
    border-left: 0px;
    border-right: 0px;
    outline: none;
  }

  #wrapLeft{
    position: relative;
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
    float: left
  }
  #wrapRight{
    position: relative;
    width: 65%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    float: right;
  }
  #clear{
    clear:both;
  }

  </style>

<div id="status">
  <div id ="wrapLeft">
    <input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
    <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
  </div>
  <div id ="wrapRight">
    <input type="text" placeholder="url"/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="url"/>
  </div>
  <div id="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the property of your id in css:

```
white-space: pre;
```

See the documentation for this property:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

Answer (score 0):

You are using *white-space: pre* on the container *status* along with indenting your code with *extra spaces*.
A better approach would be to remove that property and use padding on wrapLeft and wrapRight.

In your current code, try removing vertical space from *wrapRight* like this.

```
<div id="status">
  <div id ="wrapLeft">
    <input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
    <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
  </div><div id ="wrapRight">
    <input type="text" placeholder="url"/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="url"/>
  </div>
  <div id="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Additional spacing and offset comes from white spaces you display with `white-space: pre`. These white spaces comes from indents between html tags. You need to remove that property from `#status` and put it in separate element (`<p>` for example) which would contain just text you want to cut with `text-overflow: ellipsis`.

Answer (score 0):

## That should fix it

```css
body {
    font-family: "Segoe UI", "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
  }      #status {
    /* avoid an excessively wide status text */
    white-space: pre;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 600px
  }
  input{
    width:100px;
    height:25px;
    border-top:0px;
    border-left: 0px;
    border-right: 0px;
    outline: none;
  }
  #wrapLeft,#wrapRight{
    display: inline-block;
  }
  #wrapLeft{
    position: relative;
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
  }
  #wrapRight{
    position: relative;
    width: 65%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
  }
```

```html
<div id="status">
  <div id ="wrapLeft">
    <input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
    <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
  </div><!--
--><div id ="wrapRight">
    <input type="text" placeholder="url"/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="url"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

the `<!-- -->` for spaceing the code

[if you need support for ie7](https://coderwall.com/p/5m0srg/beware-of-inline-block)